Calculation of coordinates in PGFplots axis environment
I have already read this post and some others, but have not yet been able to apply the solution to my problem.
Here is a minimal example which works:

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,plotmarks,bending,arrows.meta,calc,angles,math,quotes}          
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}        
\newlength{\fwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \setlength{\fwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=\fwidth,
        height=\fwidth,
        at={(0\fwidth,0\fwidth)},
        scale only axis,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=5,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=18,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=18,
        axis x line=bottom, 
        axis y line=left,
        %axis lines=middle,
        ylabel near ticks,
        xlabel near ticks,
        ylabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        xlabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        legend style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        ticklabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        xlabel={$x$ in \unit{m}},
        ylabel={$y$ in \unit{m}},
        axis line style = thick,
    ]
    \tikzmath{\thettta=35;\xxx=15;\yyy=15;}
    \coordinate[] (orig)                 at (axis cs: 0.0, 0.0){};
    \coordinate[label=right:$\boldsymbol{q}_j$] (qj)  at (axis cs: \xxx, \yyy){};
    \coordinate[] (usv)                  at ($(\xxx,0)+tan(\thettta)*(0,\yyy)$){};
    \coordinate[] (left)                 at (orig |- qj){};
    \coordinate[] (bottom)               at (qj |- orig){};
    \coordinate[] (leftLine)             at ($(left)-cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(0,\yyy)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(\xxx,0)$){};
    \coordinate[] (bottomLine)           at ($(bottom)-(\xxx,0)+cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(\xxx,0)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(0,\yyy)$){};
    %
    \draw[-,red,thick](left)--(qj);
    \draw[-,red,thick](bottom)--(qj);
    \draw[-,black,thick](orig)--(usv);
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (qj) {};
    \node[anchor=south west, yshift=2mm] (usvText) at (orig) {$\boldsymbol{p}$};
    %
    \draw[-,blue,thick](left)--(leftLine) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {$\cos{\theta} \left(\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{p}\right)_y$};
    \draw[-,blue,thick](bottom)--(bottomLine) node [midway, below, sloped, xshift=-1mm] (TextNode) {$\sin{\theta} \left(\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{p}\right)_x$};
    %
    \pic [draw,thick,-latex, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle = bottom--orig--usv};
    \pic [draw,black,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=., angle radius=0.25cm] {right angle = left--leftLine--orig}; 
    \pic [draw,black,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=., angle radius=0.25cm] {right angle = bottom--bottomLine--usv}; 
    %
    \end{axis} 
    %
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (orig) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Some figure caption.}
  \label{fig:safeSetC}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}

Note that the entire image is parameterized by three variables.
Here is a slightly different example, where the axis limits are different from the first version:

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,plotmarks,bending,arrows.meta,calc,angles,math,quotes}                      
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}        
\newlength{\fwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \setlength{\fwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=\fwidth,
        height=\fwidth,
        at={(0\fwidth,0\fwidth)},
        scale only axis,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=5,
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=18,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=18,
        %axis x line=bottom, 
        %axis y line=left,
        axis lines=middle,
        ylabel near ticks,
        xlabel near ticks,
        ylabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        xlabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        legend style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        ticklabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        xlabel={$x$ in \unit{m}},
        ylabel={$y$ in \unit{m}},
        axis line style = thick,
    ]
    \tikzmath{\thettta=35;\xxx=15;\yyy=15;}
    \coordinate[] (orig)                 at (axis cs: 0.0, 0.0){};
    \coordinate[label=right:$\boldsymbol{q}_j$] (qj)  at (axis cs: \xxx, \yyy){};
    \coordinate[] (usv)                  at ($(\xxx,0)+tan(\thettta)*(0,\yyy)$){};
    \coordinate[] (left)                 at (orig |- qj){};
    \coordinate[] (bottom)               at (qj |- orig){};
    \coordinate[] (leftLine)             at ($(left)-cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(0,\yyy)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(\xxx,0)$){};
    \coordinate[] (bottomLine)           at ($(bottom)-(\xxx,0)+cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(\xxx,0)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(0,\yyy)$){};
    %
    \draw[-,red,thick](left)--(qj);
    \draw[-,red,thick](bottom)--(qj);
    \draw[-,black,thick](orig)--(usv);
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (qj) {};
    \node[anchor=south west, yshift=2mm] (usvText) at (orig) {$\boldsymbol{p}$};
    %
    \draw[-,blue,thick](left)--(leftLine) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {$\cos{\theta} \left(\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{p}\right)_y$};
    \draw[-,blue,thick](bottom)--(bottomLine) node [midway, below, sloped, xshift=-1mm] (TextNode) {$\sin{\theta} \left(\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{p}\right)_x$};
    %
    \pic [draw,thick,-latex, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle = bottom--orig--usv};
    \pic [draw,black,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=., angle radius=0.25cm] {right angle = left--leftLine--orig}; 
    \pic [draw,black,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=., angle radius=0.25cm] {right angle = bottom--bottomLine--usv}; 
    %
    \end{axis} 
    %
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (orig) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Some figure caption.}
  \label{fig:safeSetC}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}

I would like to make the second example work with the changed axis limits, which I have not been able to do so far.
The parts of the code where the calculation of the coordinates fails is in the definition of the coordinate (usv),(leftLine) and (bottomLine).
A difference from the above mentioned post is, that I have a predefined width and height of the axis and therefore can't just shift the coordinates by the origin, since there is also some scaling factor involved.
Edit: I removed the green object from the plot to shorten the code.

Sorry, could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish? Also, I would mention that many of the packages seem to be not related to the tikzpicture. Best!

Thank you for your feedback @Jasper, the post should be clearer now. I have also removed some of the package imports.

Please create a Minimal Working Example. Encoding, geometry, labels, legend, marks, styles, pic, units, arrows, math and more has nothing to do with your question.

I spent some time looking at it, but I could not identify why changing the xmin and ymin values causes the usv coordinate to be calculated differently. That is, it is scaled compared to the other coordinates.

I took me some times before I understood the issue is the two right angles. I think the question could be clearer. You can still remove lot of code unrelated with your issue.

@Jasper yes the calculation of the coordinate named usv, as well the two coordinates leftLine and bottomLine fails, while the other coordinates still work. So I assume that due to the use of the calculations inside $...$ the reference to the axis cs gets lost..?

Turns out all it took was a new day, some sleep and some math.
By shifting and rescaling everything by the origin coordinate orig I was able to produce the desired behavior.
Replacing the coordinate calculation by the following code leads to the below result:
\tikzmath{\thettta=35;\xxx=15;\yyy=15;}
\coordinate[] (orig)                 at (axis cs: 0.0, 0.0){};
\coordinate[label=right:$\boldsymbol{q}_j$] (qj)  at (axis cs: \xxx, \yyy){};
\coordinate[] (left)                 at (orig |- qj){};
\coordinate[] (bottom)               at (qj |- orig){};
\coordinate[] (usv)                  at ($(bottom)+tan(\thettta)*(left)-tan(\thettta)*(orig)$){};
\coordinate[] (leftLine)             at ($(left)-cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(left)+cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(orig)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(bottom)-cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(orig)$){};
\coordinate[] (bottomLine)           at ($(orig)+cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(bottom)-cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(orig)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(left)-cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(orig)$){};


The full code than looks like this:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}     
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,plotmarks,bending,arrows.meta,calc,angles,math,quotes}                      
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}        
\newlength{\fwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \setlength{\fwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=\fwidth,
        height=\fwidth,
        at={(0\fwidth,0\fwidth)},
        scale only axis,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=5,
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=18,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=18,
        axis lines=middle,
        ylabel near ticks,
        xlabel near ticks,
        ylabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        xlabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        legend style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        ticklabel style={font=\small\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont},
        xlabel={$x$ in \unit{m}},
        ylabel={$y$ in \unit{m}},
        axis line style = thick,
    ]
    \tikzmath{\thettta=35;\xxx=15;\yyy=15;}
    \coordinate[] (orig)                 at (axis cs: 0.0, 0.0){};
    \coordinate[label=right:$\boldsymbol{q}_j$] (qj)  at (axis cs: \xxx, \yyy){};
    \coordinate[] (left)                 at (orig |- qj){};
    \coordinate[] (bottom)               at (qj |- orig){};
    \coordinate[] (usv)                  at ($(bottom)+tan(\thettta)*(left)-tan(\thettta)*(orig)$){};
    \coordinate[] (leftLine)             at ($(left)-cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(left)+cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(orig)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(bottom)-cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(orig)$){};
    \coordinate[] (bottomLine)           at ($(orig)+cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(bottom)-cos(\thettta)*cos(\thettta)*(orig)+cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(left)-cos(\thettta)*sin(\thettta)*(orig)$){};
    %
    \draw[-,red,thick](left)--(qj);
    \draw[-,red,thick](bottom)--(qj);
    \draw[-,black,thick](orig)--(usv);
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (qj) {};
    \node[anchor=south west, yshift=2mm] (usvText) at (orig) {$\boldsymbol{p}$};
    %
    \draw[-,blue,thick](left)--(leftLine) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {$\cos{\theta} \left(\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{p}\right)_y$};
    \draw[-,blue,thick](bottom)--(bottomLine) node [midway, below, sloped, xshift=-1mm] (TextNode) {$\sin{\theta} \left(\boldsymbol{q}_j-\boldsymbol{p}\right)_x$};
    %
    \pic [draw,thick,-latex, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle = bottom--orig--usv};
    \pic [draw,black,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=., angle radius=0.25cm] {right angle = left--leftLine--orig}; 
    \pic [draw,black,thick,angle eccentricity=.5,pic text=., angle radius=0.25cm] {right angle = bottom--bottomLine--usv}; 
    %
    \end{axis} 
    %
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (orig) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Some figure caption.}
  \label{fig:safeSetC}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}


Since your original example is quite complicated, could you please add after the code snippet a complete Minimal Working Example (MWE)? The snippet is due to its compactness better to understand the changes, but reproducing it requires copying code from the question, which should be avoided.

Hi @dsacre, you're right. I've just done that, thanks for suggesting it.
